# C# can't split a string into an array by newline (from StreamReader)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, char

```
StreamReader login = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Me/Documents/logins.txt");
            string ar = login.ReadToEnd();
            string[] names = ar.Split("\r\n");
login.Close();
```

I'm reading from a file a set of logins, exampled as "username,password" then a newline as "usr,pwd" or something else. I want to split the txt file into a set of arrays by splitting at the start of a new line, but "\r\n" doesn't seem to be working, coming up with the error "cannot convert from string to char". I have tried Environment.Newline, but that is not working either, coming with the same error message.

Comment: Why not just use [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) needs an array or eiter `char` or `string` values to split on. You need to change your code to:

```
string[] names = ar.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now. Just curious, what does the StringSplitOptions do? Why does it make a difference?

Comment: @EdwardPugh - It's used to specify whether you get lines which are empty (`None`) or if it should remove empty lines from the resulting array (`RemoveEmptyEntries`)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dealing with a stream just use [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_)

```
string[] names = File.ReadAllLines("C:/Users/Me/Documents/logins.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was told to use stream, but I was just wondering, what's the difference between each one?

Comment: The difference is that `File.ReadAllLines` basically handles opening and closing the stream and reading in the lines for you.  You can check out the implementation [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,675b2259e8706c26)

Answer (score 1):

You can read each line individually like so:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathToFile)) {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

This may be preferable as you don't have to rely on the line return type to be correct using a char